# Converting a system of second order ODE's to a system in first order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

Given the two equations $$x''=-k^2 x, \enspace\enspace y''=-k^2y$$

and initial conditions $x(0)=a,x'(0)=0,y(0)=0,y'(0)=b$, where $a,b>0$ I want to convert this into a first order system which is solvable.

I make the substitutions $$x=y_1, \enspace\enspace x'=y_2,\enspace\enspace y=y_3,\enspace\enspace y'=y_4 $$

Differentiating these gives $x'=y'_1$, $x''=y'_2$, $y'=y'_3$, and $y''=y'_4$. With these substitutions, we would have first order equations $$y'_2=-k^2y_1,\enspace\enspace y'_4=-k^2y_3$$

and the initial conditions would be $y_1(0)=a,y_2(0)=0,y_3(0)=0,y_4(0)=b.$ Does this make sense, and is this a system we can solve?

Comment: Yes, except that you've left out two of the equations: $y_1' = y_2$ and $y_3' = y_4$.

Comment: So I want to have four equations in four unknowns?